# Express handler function parameter execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, express, parameters

The express route is setup with the following

```
var users = require('../../app/controllers/users.server.controller');
// Set up the 'signout' route
app.get('/signout', users.signout);
```

However, since the parenthesis aren't present, this means that the function users.signout is being passed and not executed?

The file on github can be found [here](https://github.com/amoshaviv/mean-web-development/blob/09e066bc63c50f136320707d1901558b9ab2c33d/Chapter%2011/3285OS_11_01/app/routes/users.server.routes.js#L56)

The users.signout function looks like the following

```
// Create a new controller method for signing out
exports.signout = function(req, res) {
    // Use the Passport 'logout' method to logout
    req.logout();

    // Redirect the user back to the main application page
    res.redirect('/');
};
```

The file on github can be found [here](https://github.com/amoshaviv/mean-web-development/blob/09e066bc63c50f136320707d1901558b9ab2c33d/Chapter%2011/3285OS_11_01/app/controllers/users.server.controller.js#L146)

Why is users.signout executed? And how does it get passed the req and res parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use

```
app.get('/signout', users.signout);
```

Express.js basically stores the given function, `users.signout`, internally and keeps the association with the `/signout` path.

When a request is made on this route, Express.js will get the corresponding stored function and call it, roughly in the following form:

```
// `storedFunction` corresponds to your `users.signout` function
storedFunction(expressReq, expressRes, expressNextCallback);
```

If you were to call you `users.signout` function in the call, i.e.

```
app.get('/signout', users.signout());
```

you wouldn't be able to get the `req` and `res` parameter and the `users.signout` function would actually execute right away, meaning the `app.get` function would actually receive **the result** of your function.

You can read more about this [in the documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.get.method). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

The express `app.get` function takes a string as the first argument and a function as the second. When the app listens to the routes and finds the route `'/signout'` it executes **at that instant** the function you gave in the second argument passing to it the `req` and `res` objects.
The function is not executed at the moment of the declaration `app.get('/signout', users.signout);`.

The same code could have been written as (assuming that you are using Passport to be able to use the `logout` method):

```
app.get('/signout', function(req, res) {
  // Use the Passport 'logout' method to logout
  req.logout();
  // Redirect the user back to the main application page
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

and it is actually a **function** which is passed to the second argument of `app.get`, but with explicit declaration of its logic in the same place.